# iframe calling javascript function in another iframe?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have a page with two iframes; a slideshow and an ad.  Is is possible to have the slideshow iframe call a function in the ad iframe?

Thanks!

Comment: Here is a link to how: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032770/execute-javascript-function-in-a-another-iframe-when-parent-is-from-different-do

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as long as both iframes load pages from the same domain.

Comment: @Joshua, since the OP explicitly asked IF it was possible, and not HOW it could be done, I would hardly call my answer "fail". If you want a step by step guide how to do it, please post a question and I will be happy to answer it for you.