# execute javascript function in a another iframe when parent is from different domain

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, xss

The page **A.com** has 2 iframes **B.com/page1** and **B.com/page2**. 
This is the code of A.com:

```
<html><body>
    <iframe src="b.com/page1" name="iframe1" id="iframe1">
    <iframe src="b.com/page2">
</body></html>
```

I want to execute js function on **B.com/page1** from **B.com/page2**.
Both examples below works well when the parent is from the same domain but not in cross domain scenario:

```
parent.window.frames['iframe1'].SomeFunction(args);
```

or

```
parent.document.getElementById('iframe1').contentWindow.SomeFunction(args);
```

Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of

```
parent.window.frames['iframe1'].SomeFunction(args);
```

use

```
parent.frames['iframe1'].SomeFunction(args);
```

You are allowed to traverse the `frames` collection of any window that you can reference, but in this case you are trying to traverse the recursive `window` property of `parent` (which IS the window). This is not allowed.

Comment: Sean , but window.window is exactly like window. However- I tried this `parent.window.window.window.frames['if1'].window.window.window.s2(1)`  and it did work...(or do you talk about traversing something else ?)

Answer (score 2):

No, the browser doesn't allow interacts between iframes that are not on the same domain at all.

Comment: Just to make it clear. Although the 2 iframes are from the same domain there is no direct way for them to interact because the parent is from different domain?

Comment: No, because the iframes can only "talk to" each other through the parent frame, and the frames can't access the parent frame from a different domain.

Comment: Actually, this is incorrect. He only needs to change `parent.window.frames` into `parent.frames`

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron have already told you, browsers don't allow this, but there are ways around it. You'll need to create a small hack. Eugene Gladyshev has a [post on it on his blog](http://egladysh.blogspot.com/2010/02/cross-domain-request-pattern.html).

Answer (score 0):

As Aaron states, it is not allowed to interact between iframes, but you should take a look at easyXDM, it helps with cross domain communication in javascript:

http://easyxdm.net/wp/

Here is the example you might be looking for:

http://easyxdm.net/wp/2010/03/17/sending-and-receiving-messages/