# Jquery binding function in parent from different domain

Tags: jquery, cross-domain

my problem is really similar to this one: [execute javascript function in a another iframe when parent is from different domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032770/execute-javascript-function-in-a-another-iframe-when-parent-is-from-different-do)

I have an **A.com** domain page with 2 iframe containing B.com/page1 and B.com/page2

i need to execute a function in **B.com/page2** iframe by clicking a button in **B.com/page1** (same as already linked page), **BUT** using jQuery.

Now i'm using this code in B.com/page1

```
parent.$(parent.document).trigger("myFunction", [myParams]);
```

and getting it in B.com/page2 with

```
parent.$(parent.frames).bind("myFunction", function (e, value) { localFunction(value); });
```

this works well if i load both page1 and page2 from B.com/index, but it fail when loading from A.com with error

> Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL A.com from frame
>   with URL B.com/page2. Domains, protocols and ports must match.

error is triggered by the bind function.
As already stated in the linked topic i can refeer from a iframe to other iframes in the same page using code:

```
parent.frames['page2'].myFunction(args);
```

but i still get same error from javascript console **AND** another error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'myFunction' of undefined

How i can get out of this? Thank you!

Comment: The same-origin-policy prevents you from doing what you want. Consider looking into the [window.postMessage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) function, which provides a way to send messages between pages on different domains. Browser support is relatively good ([source](http://html5test.com/compare/feature/communication-postMessage.html)).

Comment: thank you i'm looking for it right now!

Answer (score 0):

Solved using the window.postMessage function as suggest from Henrik!
i first had to B.com/page2 postMessage to A.com and then A.com postMessage to B.com/page1 :D
it works in lastest chrome, opera, firefox, ie 10, ie9, ie8, ie7 without any problem :)

B.com/page2 sends it message with:

```
parent.postMessage("go!!!!!", $('#parentPage').val());
```

(i had the parent page to write its ip in a hidden div called "parentPage")
then parent page get the event with

```
var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
var eventer = window[eventMethod];
var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";
eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        //triggered code here
}, false);
```

and re-send message with this

```
win.postMessage(
                "go",
                targetPage);
```

B.com/page1 receive message with:

```
window.onmessage = function (e) { /* code here */ }
```

hope it can be useful :)