# Execute javascript function in a another iframe when parent is from different domain - with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-domain

Yes , It's a similar question as in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3032770/execute-javascript-function-in-a-another-iframe-when-parent-is-from-different-do) , but mine is tagged with jquery.

in short : I have this scenario :

[image]

both documents (`x.B.com` and `y.B.com`) has `document.domain="B.com"`;

But lets say Im in `y.B.com` and I want to execute `work()`

Running `parent.frames['if1'].work(2);`  -- **is working.**

But I tried doing it with jQuery : (didn't succeed)

- `$('#if1', parent.document).contents().work(2);`
- `$('#if1', parent.document)[0].work(2);`

How can I do it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can do it without jQuery, the amount of text you need to type is less without jQuery, and the code is easier to understanding without jQuery, then why use jQuery?

**jQuery can't traverse a document from a different domain.**

this was failed :

`$('#if1', parent.document)...`

while this was OK

`parent.frames['if1']....`

Comment: The answer is you can't because jQuery can't traverse a document from a different domain.